# mysql удаление parent и child

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_parent` (`parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_parent` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Нужно что бы при удалении записи удалялись все дочерние записи, при данной структуре БД не вставляются записи с нулевым **parent**, как это исправить?
ошибка **#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row**

//////////////////////////////////////

решение:

```
 `parent` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
```

таким образом это надо было записать

Answer (score 1):

Может

```
  `parent` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
```

?

Comment: не совсем, `parent` int(10) unsigned default NULL, самое то

Comment: @LLIAKAJI подправил ответ